# Formal charge of oxygen in protonated alcohol

Tags: formal-charge

When ethanol is attacked by positive hydrogen ion, how can the oxygen atom acquire formal positive charge? 
I tried calculation it as : $\frac{6-4}{2-1}$ which gives answer 3, but the answer should be 1. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need the answer using Lewis dot structure, so I used the same.

[image]